MATLAB calling class constructor EVERY time instance method is called
First of all, I'm quite new to using MATLAB for object-oriented programming, and I still trying to figure out how things work. However, I cannot for the life of me understand why I am have this particular issue, which seems to break the general laws of object-oriented programming as a whole.
The issue is this:
I have a quadcopter simulation where I want a quadcopter to follow a particular set of waypoints in 3D space. Each waypoint is a 12x1 column vector of the quadcopter state. I am trying to create a class way which stores a list of all waypoints, the current waypoint and the waypoint number. This list of waypoints is stored as the instance variable XXX, which is a 12xn matrix where n is the total number of waypoints, n_waypoints.
The constructor method way initialises an object with this list of waypoints, XXX and a initial waypoint counter, n of 1. As you can see, I have input the state values as column vectors within a matrix and then transposed the matrix using ' so as to not need to repetitively type semicolons.
The method getWaypoint takes inputs X and U, which are the quadcopters state and control vector in the simulation and returns X_ref, the waypoint the quadcopter should be flying to.
getWaypoint first checks if the current waypoint number is less than the total, then checks if the current waypoint has been reached by the quadcopter within some tolerance. If both of these are true, the waypoint counter is incremented and the new current waypoint is set by indexing XXX by the waypoint counter. Each call of the method returns the current waypoint as X_ref.
classdef way
    properties
        XXX
        currentWaypoint
        n_waypoints
        n
    end
    
    methods
        
        function obj = way()

            % Define waypoints + transpose
            obj.XXX = [7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ;
                       10 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 2 0 0 0;
                       10 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]' ;
            
            % Set current waypoint as first of waypoint list, XXX
            obj.currentWaypoint = obj.XXX(:,1) ;
            
            % Get number of waypoints
            obj.n_waypoints = size(obj.XXX, 1) ;
            
            % Initialise waypoint number counter
            obj.n = 1

            end

        end
        
    
        function [X_ref] = getWaypoint(obj, X)
            
            % If path incomplete
            if obj.n < obj.n_waypoints

                % If quadcopter has reached the current waypoint within certain tolerance 
                if sum(abs(X - obj.currentWaypoint)) < 0.1
                
                
                    % Increment waypoint number counter
                    obj.n = obj.n + 1

                    % Set current waypoint from waypoint list, XXX
                    obj.currentWaypoint = obj.XXX(:, obj.n) ;

                end
                
            end
            
            % Return current waypoint as X_ref
            X_ref = obj.currentWaypoint ;

        end

    end

end

In another script, way is called whilst initialising the simulation to construct an instance called 'path'
path = way()

Then in a while loop which represents every timestep of the simulation, the function is called:
 X_ref = path.getWaypoint(X)

When the quadcopter reaches the current waypoint within the tolerance, the function is triggered to increment the waypoint counter, and successfully, the next waypoint vector is returnd.
However, on the next timestep, when this method is called, the waypoint counter is returned to 1, and so the current waypoint. I can only deduce that this is to do with the constructor method way being called whenever the getWaypoint method is called.
But why is this happening? I've made no mention of 'way' anywhere else inside the while loop. Does MATLAB just work this way?
I tried copying MATLAB documentation - that hasn't got me too far. I tried initialising these variables in the 'properties' section but I had syntax errors.

No, the constructor is not called repeatedly.
What happens is that in MATLAB, all function calls take the input arguments by value, not reference. You cannot change the input arguments.
path.getWaypoint(X) is the same as getWaypoint(path,X), the object is passed as the first input argument. And it is passed by value: when you modify the object inside the class method, you modify the copy, not the object owned by the caller.
Typically in MATLAB you’d define class methods that modify the object to return the modified object:
function [obj, X_ref] = getWaypoint(obj, X)

and then call it
[path, X_ref] = getWaypoint(path, X);

A way around this traditional syntax is to derive the class from handle. This causes all copies of an object to reference the same underlying data. It is intended for objects you cannot copy, such as one representing an open file on disk or a window on the screen. But it is commonly abused to make syntax less MATLAB-y and more similar to that of other languages. But be careful! You can no longer copy the object!
classdef way < handle
    properties
        XXX
        currentWaypoint
        n_waypoints
        n
    end
    
    methods

        function [X_ref] = getWaypoint(obj, X)
        % …


See this documentation page for more information.
